# How to integrate paypal recurring gem with Spree

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway, spree, recurring-billing

I am integrating paypal payment method in spree with recurring billing. Has anyone tried with recurring billing with paypal. As I don't get the payment options in Spree configurations once I add paypal-recurring gem in my Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Spree does not have support for recurring billing out of the box.  I don't know of any extensions which currently do the job for this, so you may need to consider writing your own.

The [Spree Extension Guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/extensions_tutorial.html) is a good place to start, but I warn you that this is a large undertaking.  If you have a small number of products, you may want to consider using a service like [Recurly](http://recurly.com/) to manage your subscription plans and skip Spree entirely.